# if block doesn't trigger, even when it should

Tags: python

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here...

```
accountManager = open("accountManager.txt","r")
userNameInvalid = True
while userNameInvalid == True:
    userName = input("Username (this is public): ")
    userNameLine = 0
    for line in accountManager.readlines():
        if (((userNameLine % 6) == 2) and (userName == line)):
            print("The username \"" + userName + "\" taken, please choose another one.")
            userNameInvalid = True
            break
        userNameInvalid = False
        userNameLine += 1
```

For context: accountManager is a txt file (currently open in 'r' mode) that looks like the following:

```
*empty line*
Real name 1
Username 1
Email 1
Notes 1
*empty line*
*empty line*
Real name 2
Username 2
Email 2
Notes 2
*empty line*
*empty line*
Real name 3
Username 3
Email 3
Notes 3
*empty line*
```

As you can see, it comes in little "chunks" of 6 lines, the number of which would be unknown.

**What I want it to do:**

*Only when the input is "Username 1", "Username 2" or "Username 3", the if statement should trigger.*

**What happens:**

*if statement never runs*

### UPDATE:

***If statement now runs, but now, if you at first enter a taken username, it will get stuck in the while loop and never get out... Why?***

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in variables. You can also `print(userNameLine % 6)` or `print( (userNameLine % 6) == 2 )`, etc. OR maybe check `if line.startswith("Username")` ?

Comment: BTW: line may have "\n" at the end and you may have to remove it before compare it.

Comment: `userNameInvalid` is already set to `True` why the double implication in the `while` loop, just do `while userNameInvalid:` just a tip...and what file is this opening? could you post that section of the code as well,

Comment: @FishingCode what do you mean it's already set to true? if it doesn't meet the if on the first run of the for loop it becomes false, and if it does trigger the second time, it would change it from false to true.

Comment: the `for` loop doesn't run first, the `while` loop is first, top-down, `userNameInvalid` is already set to `True` so why the does while loop check to see if it's `True` when it is already?

Comment: @FishingCode That line is inside the for loop though

Comment: the `for` loop is **nested** in the `while` loop, but unless there is another `for` loop, then it may be missing code...

Comment: @FishingCode litteraly 2 lines below there is a line that might have turned it false m8, it's not that hard

Comment: Have you done any debugging? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the condition `userName == line` is never true. When you read a line using `f.read()`, or `f.readlines()`, each line is terminated with the new line character `\n`. So, for example, instead of "Username 1", the line will be "Username 1\n". A simple way to solve this is to append "\n" to the comparison string `userName` as the following.

`userName = input("Username (this is public): ") + "\n"`

Also, `f.readlines()` returns an empty list if you don't reset the file object. You can get stuck in the while loop as the result. You can fix it using `f.seek(0)`, but instead of re-reading the file multiple times, save the list of lines for re-use.

```py
accountManager = open("accountManager.txt","r")
userNameInvalid = True
lines = accountManager.readlines()
while userNameInvalid == True:
    userName = input("Username (this is public): ")
    userNameLine = 0
    for line in lines:
        if userNameLine % 6 == 2 and userName == line:
            print("The username \"" + userName + "\" taken, please choose another one.")
            userNameInvalid = True
            break
        userNameInvalid = False
        userNameLine += 1
```

Comment: Yep! that worked, btw, ended up adding the "\n" to username in the if statement... that way I can use the userName variable later without having to remove the /n

Comment: But it gets stuck in the while loop

Comment: I see what's wrong. You need to rewind the file back to the beginning. Otherwise, `accountManager.readlines()` will return an empty array after the first time it is called.

Comment: Wow! thank you, just added "accountManager.seek(0)" and it worked great

Answer (score 0):

As you have it the code is hard to follow. I would restructure the code by first reading all the data into a more usable format, and only then validate it. You can take each section of user data and place them into a list of small dicts.

Using a while loop and `iter`/`next` you could pretty easily parse the data. You should also strip the line to remove extra whitespace:

```
raw_data = iter(accountManager.readlines())
user_data = []
try:
    while True:
        next(raw_data)  # clear blank line
        user_data.append(
            {
                'real_name': next(raw_data).strip(),
                'username': next(raw_data).strip(),
                'email': next(raw_data).strip(),
                'notes': next(raw_data).strip(),
            }
        )
        next(raw_data)  # clear blank line
except StopIteration:  # no more values in raw_data iter
    pass  # do nothing, we expect this
```

Once you have the data, I would use a `set` to check for duplicates:

```
username_invalid = False
usernames = set()
for data in user_data:
    username = data['username']
    if username in usernames:
        print(
            f'The username "{username}" '
            'is taken, please choose another one.'
        )
        username_invalid = True
        break
    usernames.add(username)
```